# Delphi VCL app, how to disable the default behavior of a KeyDown event?

Tags: delphi, events, event-handling, keyboard-events, keydown

While I was reading code, I found that in the `KeyDown` event you can set `Key := 0;` to stop processing the event any further. For example: [`TIncrementalForm.FormKeyDown`](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/blob/ea98167bc3f4486baa6ca76963c5dd49f6108e04/Source/IncrementalFrm.pas#L186) is coded as:

```
procedure TIncrementalForm.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then begin
    Key := 0; // Stop processing by input window
    if Shift = [ssShift] then
      btnPrevClick(nil)
    else
      btnNextClick(nil);
  end;
end;
```

Another example is from [`unit FindFrm`](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/blob/ea98167bc3f4486baa6ca76963c5dd49f6108e04/Source/FindFrm.pas#L575):

```
procedure TFindForm.cboFindTextKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_TAB then begin
    cboFindText.SelText := #9;
    Key := 0; // prevent propagation
  end;
end;
```

I tested it myself, but it doesn't work:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  private const
    VK_X = Ord('X');
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_X then
  begin
    Key := 0;
    Memo2.Lines.Add('yes');
  end;
end;

end.
```

My intention is: whenever the user holds down the key <kbd>x</kbd> in the `TMemo` control I do some business logic (i.e. add "yes" to the memo) and stop further processing. But the result is that the key <kbd>x</kbd> is still inserted to the `TMemo` text. I want to know how to disable the default key holding down event behavior (inserting the corresponding key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here (no pun intended) is to use `OnKeyPress` instead of `OnKeyDown`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = 'x' then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('yes');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: KeyPress doesn't have the additional parameter `Shift: TShiftState`. In my actually code, I need to test the `TShiftState` value, so I have to use KeyDown event. Is there a way to do it for the `KeyDown` event?

Comment: @FajelaTajkiya: Which particular modifier key are you interested in? If `Shift`, this is trivial: Use `if Key = 'x' then` for `X` and `if Key = 'X' then` for `Shift+X`.

Comment: It's `ctrl` and `ctrl + alt`.

Comment: If so, the best approach by far is to drop a `TActionList` on your form. Double-click it. Create an action, name it `aTestAction` and set its `ShortCut` to `Ctrl+X`. As its `OnExecute` handler, write `Memo1.Lines.Add('yes')`. Then try Ctrl+X at runtime. You'll see that your `OnExecute` is executed and no cutting is done in the memo. That is, `Ctrl+X` is handled by your action and the poor memo will never even realise that someone pressed `Ctrl+X`. But beware that this will disable `Ctrl+X` (cutting) in your entire application. This can be worked around.

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll give it a try. Thank you for your valuable time!

Comment: in the first example of my code, the `KeyDown` event hander, includes the statement `Key := 0; // Stop processing by input window`. Does this statement really prevent further processing?

Comment: @FajelaTajkiya: Mostly not. You still get the KeyPress and the KeyUp.

Comment: _Use if Key = 'x' then for X and if Key = 'X' then for Shift+X_ - Unless CAPS LOCK is on :-)

Comment: @HeartWare: Correct!

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a comment, but I need to publish code, so...

You can test the *current* Shift-state using these functions:

```
CONST
  VK_ALT        = VK_MENU;
  VK_CTRL       = VK_CONTROL;

FUNCTION KeyPressed(VirtualKey : WORD) : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=(GetKeyState(VirtualKey) AND $80000000<>0)
  END;

FUNCTION Shift : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=KeyPressed(VK_SHIFT)
  END;

FUNCTION Alt : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=KeyPressed(VK_ALT)
  END;

FUNCTION Ctrl : BOOLEAN;
  BEGIN
    Result:=KeyPressed(VK_CTRL)
  END;
```

But beware that you must call these function at the tail end of a keyboard event and before a new keyboard event occurs, as this call will return the state as it was from the *latest* keyboard event and not the one that necessarily were active at the time you want (if you call it outside the keyboard event handler).

Comment: Just wanted to mention that GetKeyState (according to the documentation) retrieves the state of the key when the input message was generated and is usually what you want.  GetAsyncKeyState retrieves the "right now" value.

Comment: Yes, but that requires that you call it at the right time (ie. before the next key is pressed). I'll clarify it in the description...

Comment: When testing for more than one shift key (i.e. `CTRL+ALT`) it is performance wise a better approach to call `KeyPressed( VK_CTRL or VK_ALT )` instead of the other functions individually. Which shows how fast supposed helpers become futile.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Are you absolutely sure about that? VK_CTRL and VK_ALT are not bitmasks - they are key codes. VK_CTRL = $11 and VK_ALT = $12. (VK_CTRL OR VK_ALT) = $13 which is also the value of VK_PAUSE so how are we to distinguish between "VK_CTRL OR VK_ALT" ($13) and "VK_PAUSE" (also $13) being pressed, if we pass $13 as the value to KeyPressed??? Not to mention that your approach doesn't allow you to test for SHIFT and CTRL at the same time, as VK_SHIFT =$10 and VK_CTRL = $11 and (VK_SHIFT OR VK_CTRL) = $11 = VK_CTRL so the "VK_SHIFT" is ignored in that "OR".

Comment: Virtual Key Codes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: You are right and I'm wrong - confused it with [`GetKeyboardState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate) which is able to question multiple keys at once without risking to get inconsistent results because they occur at different times.